# indexOf() String Class Java

Tags: java

I need help with comparing an `indexOf` from a string with an array of strings and display the correct matches.

```
public static void printvehicleMAKE(ServiceAppointment[] services, Scanner input){

    System.out.print("Enter vehicle make: ");

    String make = input.next();
    String model = make.substring(0,3);

    System.out.println(model);

    boolean flag = false;

    System.out.println("Details of all vehicles manufactured by " +make+" : ");
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        if(model.equalsIgnoreCase(services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL())){
            System.out.printf("\n%10s%15s%20s", services[i].getregoNUMBER(),
                    services[i].getbuildYEAR(), services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL());
            flag = true;
            }

    }

    if(flag==false)
        System.out.print("No service appointments were found for vehicles " 
                + "made by " + make);   
}
```

Example. If I enter "toyota" or "aston", I want it to compare the 1st/2nd character of the string and return the matches from the array of strings.

Comment: And your actual problem is?

Comment: If i enter "to", i want it to return the string/s that matches the first 2 characters of the strings in the array list. Example, if i enter "as", it will display "aston martin" or "to", it will display "toyota camry" and so forth.

I'm not sure if indexOf() method is really helpful or not when it comes to comparing strings.

Comment: Right now, if i enter "to", it will display "No service appointments were found for vehicles" instead of "toyota camry" or other strings that matches the first 2 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL())
```

gives the full string as in "Toyota Camry" you must adjust your filter criteria. Currently you compare `"to"` with `"Toyota Camry"`. This does not match. So you should use this instead

```
model.equalsIgnoreCase(services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL().substring(0,3))
```

Comment: Awesome! it worked! Thank you very much for your help. ^.^ I knew it was something really simple.